# Under what conditions will a "long polling" PHP script cease to execute?

Tags: php, jquery, long-integer

Does it have to stop itself? What if someone visits my site, starts the script on the server, and then leaves (or his phone hibernates)? I'm using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as [it times out](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), which is usually 30-60 seconds after the script starts, but you can change it.

Comment: that's it? so for a chat script, i have to keep re-starting it every 30 seconds or so?

Comment: You can return an empty result after about 28 seconds, or just let the script time out and make jQuery handle the error. The AJAX client should then send a new long-poll request. Wash, rinse, repeat. Anyway, thanks to the time limit, if somebody requests a long poll and just turns off his phone, you won't have a useless script running on your server for more than 30 seconds.